# Assinar digitalmente documentos usando a Chave Móvel Digital do Cartão de Cidadão

Tags: api, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Desenvolvi uma APP em Apache Cordova (HTML5 e Javascript), que está em produção e já tem milhares de utilizadores, e preciso agora que os utilizadores, cidadãos portugueses, assinem digitalmente um documento. A Administração Pública em Portugal tem uma [Chave Móvel Digital](https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/a-chave-movel-digital) que permite a autenticação dos cidadãos através de um SMS para o telemóvel, permitindo também a assinatura digital.

Alguém tem conhecimento de alguma API ou do código necessário para se efetuar essa assinatura? Ando a pesquisar muito, mas a documentação é muito escassa.

Answer (score 2):

O "Perguntas Frequentes" do site, disponível em

https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/cmd-faqs

menciona isto:

> **Posso instalar o mecanismo de autenticação da Chave Móvel Digital no meu serviço web?**
>
> Este serviço apenas está disponível para as entidades da Administração Pública. Para realizar a integração com este método de autenticação pode contactar a Agência para a Modernização Administrativa (AMA) através do contacto info.portaldocidadao@ama.pt.

Creio que o melhor seja entrar em contato pelo email indicado no site.

Caso você não represente uma entidade da Administração Pública, talvez ainda consiga alguma outra maneira de identificar o usuário fazendo com que este assine algum documento gerado por você, e você confira a validade do documento, mas é mera especulação minha.

Comment: Apenas uma atualização. Entrei em contacto com eles e apresentar-me preços para uso do serviço,  proibitivos e ridiculamente elevados. É assim o "serviço público".

Answer (score 0):

O serviço de Chave Móvel Digital (CMD) já se encontra disponível para utilização por entidades privadas.
No entanto este serviço tem um custo associado consoante o volume de autenticações/assinaturas.

Para receberes informações de como aceder ao serviço envia um email com o pedido de informações para ama@ama.pt.

Comment: Confirmo. E o custo é simplesmente ridículo de tal astronómico que é.

Comment: Concordo, é ridículo que o que deveria ser um serviço público seja utilizado para fazer negócio.